# How can I change the color of a specific cell in UICollectionView

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

The code is pretty simple, but I don't know why it doesn't work. What I am trying to do is to change the color of the 5th cel or the one in the second column and second row to black, instead of white.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var x: UICollectionView!

    var place = NSIndexPath(forItem: 1, inSection: 1)

    @IBAction func y(sender: AnyObject) {

        x.cellForItemAtIndexPath(place)?.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()

    }

    @IBAction func z(sender: AnyObject) {

        x.cellForItemAtIndexPath(place)?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the background of the cell, then its the contentView which you have to manage, for example :

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

So in your case you may replace your functions with :

```
@IBAction func y(sender: AnyObject) {

    self.x.cellForItemAtIndexPath(place)?.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()

}

@IBAction func z(sender: AnyObject) {

    self.x.cellForItemAtIndexPath(place)?.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

}
```

Also if you are changing the fifth cell background color your indexPath should be :

```
var place = NSIndexPath(forItem: 4, inSection: 0)
```

I've noticed that you are trying to do row 1 and column 1 so its forItem: 1 and inSection: 1, it doesn't work like that in IOS. UICollectionView has items and sections, Items in collectionView start from left to write item0 item1 item2.. etc and by default its in section 0, for example you add another section which will be section number 1 to put another items in it, which will be item0,item2,item3.. etc but its in section 1 and so on, More about it here : [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/)

Be sure that you set the datasource to your ViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDataSource {

        override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        x.dataSource = self

    }


     func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {

        return 1
    }


     func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return 20
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)

    // Configure the cell


    return cell
  }
}
```

It should work perfectly, good luck !

Comment: @Aaoli There is an error: Type ViewController does not conform to protocol 'UIViewDataSource', and my CollectionView has three lines and three columns, the NSIndexPath would still be(forItem: 4, inSection: 0)?

Comment: @PKLJ, You should add another method called `cellForItemAtIndexPath`, check my answer, yes it will still be item 4 (starting from 0,1,2,3,4) so 4 is item number 5 ! :)

Comment: @Aaoli Just one more question (it worked by the way, thanks), what do the three last methods do? Specially the reuseIdentifier parameter.

Comment: @PKLJ, You are welcome ! The reuseIdentifier is the name of your cell assigned for cell in storyboard !? Is that what you asked for ?

Comment: @PKLJ well these methods must be used to set the data to the collectionView , numberOfSections method returns how many section you want to do in your collectionView let's say for example section for love wallpapers and section for nature wallpaper then you need to return 2 sections. NumberOfItemsInSection to manage the number of items in each section. Last method is cellForItematIndexPath is to manage cell in the view , where you can create views buttons,labels and that's will be called custom cell. You will find a lot of tutorials about it and I recommend you do little research about it !